# Sending serialized data over POST request

Tags: python, http, post, flask, request

First thing, I'm not very used to HTTP request, so bear with me if I make some stupid mistakes or assumption that are completely wrong.

I'm trying to send an image using a POST request using Flask, the code that I'm using is the one that can be found on this link: 
https://gist.github.com/kylehounslow/767fb72fde2ebdd010a0bf4242371594

Basically it encodes the image using cv2, than sends it over in the POST request, I could get that to work but I wanted to send some more information, therefore I rewrote the request as:

```
payload = {'img':img_encoded.tostring(), 'name':'foo'}
response = requests.post(test_url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

this gives me an error, more specifically:

```
TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable
```

This is due to the fact that I'm encoding the image, so I tried to just send the dictionary, without dumping it to a JSON, the request goes through, but now I dont know how to decode the data field in the request. 
If I try to access to request.data I get this:

```
b'img=very_long_first_field_of_binary_info&name=foo'
```

How do I revert that to a dictionary?
Since I can't use json, I don't know what to do.
Thanks in advance for your help,

Mattia

Comment: To make your image data JSON serializable, consider encoding it as base64

Comment: did you try encode() json data?